# Драйвер для убунту

Tags: ubuntu

Как узнать версию сетевой карты и как установить (обновить) для нее драйвер? Работа полностью под убунтой 11,10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сетевые карты бывают разные, от обычного ethernet и wifi до какого нибудь экзотического через com порт.

Но в целом, методика такая. В консоле  исполняем команды `lspci` и `lsusb` (некоторые сетевые карты могут висеть на usb порту). Просматриваем каждое название и гуглим. В принципе важен идентификатор устройства, которые выглядит как xxxx:xxxx (где x - 0..9a..f).
Если сетевая карта съемная, то можно просто сравнить эти списки до и после.

Есть ещё один способ. Сразу после загрузки выполнить в консоле команду `dmesg` и смотреть там. Но тут часто нужно иметь опыт.